# How do I center a letter on its background-color when using the letter-spacing property?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to highlight every letter of a word in a different color by using the `background-color` property, but I want to separate the letters to give them a blocky look. The problem is that when I increase the `letter-spacing`, the highlighted parts are lopsided, not centered around the letter as I want them. Here's an example:

```
<mark style="background-color: red">t</mark><mark style="background-color: green">e</mark<mark style="background-color: blue">s</mark><mark style="background-color: yellow">t</mark>
```

```
mark
{
   color: white;
   letter-spacing: 1em;
}
```

The background extends farther to the right of the letter than the left. Is there any way to center the letter in the background, so that it's highlighted evenly on both sides? Currently, I'm using `&nbsp`s around each letter and avoiding using `letter-spacing` altogether, which works fine, but a solution that doesn't require the addition of any characters would be much nicer. What I'm currently using:

```
<mark style="background-color: red">&nbspt&nbsp</mark><mark style="background-color: green">&nbspe&nbsp</mark<mark style="background-color: blue">&nbsps&nbsp</mark><mark style="background-color: yellow">&nbspt&nbsp</mark>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they're already in separate elements, you could just use padding.

```css
mark
{
   color: white;
   padding: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<mark style="background-color: red">t</mark><mark style="background-color: green">e</mark><mark style="background-color: blue">s</mark><mark style="background-color: yellow">t</mark>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted, I don't know why I didn't think of that before.